# PDO Error Code 1060 Duplicate column name for Inserting Record to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

> I tried to Insert Record to table using PDO but its always return this error **Error : Array ( [0] => 42S21 [1] => 1060 [2] => Duplicate column name '' )**

and Sometimes inserting perfectly. I don't understand why its happened.

```
         $data=array(
            ':business_title' =>$title , 
            ':business_cover' => $cover, 
            ':business_logo' => $logo, 
            ':business_location'=>$location,
            ':business_address' =>$address, 
            ':business_contact' =>$phone , 
            ':business_email' =>$email , 
            ':business_url' =>$website ,
            ':business_category' =>$category ,
            ':business_subcategory' =>$subcategory ,
            ':business_keywords' =>$keywords ,
            ':business_full_desc' => $summary, 
            ':business_amenities' => $amenities,
            ':business_socialurl' => $socialurl,
            ':business_token' => $token,
            ':user_id' => $userid
          );
      $query = "
      INSERT INTO tablename
      (business_title,business_cover,business_logo,business_location,business_address,business_contact,business_email,business_url,business_category,business_subcategory,business_keywords,business_full_desc,business_amenities, business_socialurl,business_token, user_id)
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT :business_title,:business_cover,:business_logo,:business_location,:business_address,:business_contact,:business_email,:business_url,:business_category,:business_subcategory,:business_keywords,:business_full_desc,:business_amenities, :business_socialurl,:business_token, :user_id) AS tmp
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT user_id FROM tablename WHERE user_id = :user_id
      ) LIMIT 1
      ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is occurring when you get duplicated values in the input data. When you `SELECT` a set of constant values, MySQL automatically generates column names which match the values. For example:

```sql
SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

yields the result:

```
a   b   c
---------
a   b   c
```

Now if you

```sql
SELECT 'a', 'b', 'b'
```

You get

```
a   b   b
---------
a   b   b
```

As a result, if you then attempt to

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'a', 'b', 'b') AS tmp;
```

You will get a duplicate column error as there are two columns called `b` in the result set of the subquery.

You can work around this by giving the values column aliases, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'a' AS a, 'b' AS b, 'b' AS c) AS tmp;
```

Output:

```
a   b   c
a   b   b
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c87e309242b7dc393f0afec666f98ad0)

Note that it's not clear that you need the complexity of the query that you have, you should be able to simply:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (business_title,business_cover,business_logo,business_location,business_address,business_contact,business_email,business_url,business_category,business_subcategory,business_keywords,business_full_desc,business_amenities, business_socialurl,business_token, user_id)
SELECT :business_title,:business_cover,:business_logo,:business_location,:business_address,:business_contact,:business_email,:business_url,:business_category,:business_subcategory,:business_keywords,:business_full_desc,:business_amenities, :business_socialurl,:business_token, :user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE user_id = :user_id
)
```

See for example [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0212fb97a8da96ab9870f8097ae81848).

Comment: Thank You @Nick. Now Query Working Fine just change to business_title as business_title same all column  name